# JMSException all possible code of getErrorCode()

Tags: jms

Can any one help to find out the list of all errorCode which getErrorCode() method  of JMS Exception can throw?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single list of errorcodes available, as it depends on the vendor which is implementing the [JMS standard/interface](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jms/javadoc-102a/javax/jms/JMSException.html#getErrorCode()).

So which implementation of JMS do you use?